# How to count the number of elements in this json object?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get the number of elements for this JSON object in javascript.

```
data = 
{
    name_data: {
        35: {
            name: "AA",
        },
        47: {
            name: "BB",
        },
        48: {
            name: "CC",
        },
        49: {
            name: "DD",
        }
    }
}
```

The correct answer should be 4. My code is `data.name_data.length` but it returns an undefined object. How can the correct number of elements in this JSON object be obtained in javascript?

Comment: `JSON` is a text format.  What you have there is a Javascript object and not JSON.

Comment: JSON is an acronym for "JavaScript Object Notation"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys`:

```
 Object.keys(data).length; // returns 1
 Object.keys(data.name_data).length; // returns 4
```

Comment: How about nested elements? Is there a way to include that in the overall count as well?